# Can I encrypt my whole GPT dual-boot system drive?

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot, encryption

I have a dual-boot GPT system drive, with both a Windows 10 and a Linux, and I would love to know if there is any way for me to encrypt the whole drive (I'm talking about pre-boot secure) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally no, unless you hack the encryption support into your system firmware. UEFI needs to access the cleartext bootloader in your EFI System Partition, BIOS needs to access the cleartext bootsector, etc.

Encrypting the bootloader isn't very useful, however – it's entirely public data. You only need to ensure its *integrity,* which can be achieved in other ways such as code signing (UEFI Secure Boot) or TPM measurements. For example, BitLocker already uses the standard Secure Boot setup to verify that the bootloader's passphrase prompt hasn't been replaced with a malicious one; it also uses the TPM to make sure the disk will only auto-unlock if the boot files are verified to be legitimate.

There's an exception to this – the OPAL "self encrypting disk" feature that's found on some SSDs. If you enable OPAL hardware encryption, the disk will present a "fake" overlay boot partition first, which will then unlock the real disk contents. The downside is that you need to trust the disk to implement encryption properly (i.e. you're no longer using LUKS at that point), and it seems a bit brittle to me in general.

BitLocker can integrate with OPAL hardware encryption for the whole disk (instead of using its own software encryption for individual partitions), but I really have no idea how this interacts with other operating systems on the same disk.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear and simple answer !
I already thought one couldn't encrypt its whole drive, but this answer clarifies why and helps me lots :)